# node.js does not read and return simple HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have created a simple filereader method in node.js that takes in an html file in the same folder. However, when I try to launch it on my localhost, I receieve the message: throw new TypeError<'First argument must be a string or Buffer'>;

My node.js file is:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile('demofile1.html', function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

And my HTML code is simple as well:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>My Header</h1>
<p>My paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

If someone could please provide some insight, it would be much appreciated. I looked on both Google and StackOverflow and no solutions fixed my problem. Other node programs like outputting "Hello World" or displaying the date and time work on my localhost.

Comment: You should add `if (err) { console.error(err); }` to your `readFile` callback, it's probably a path issue

Comment: I added in the code snippet you mentioned, but nothing changes. If you have not done so, could you run it yourself and see what happens?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, maybe the type in file name, because I tried with typo and the reusult islike yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely `err` is set and `data` is `undefined`. You should always check for errors first.

Comment: Could you give me an idea of how to define data?

Comment: You don't. It's what is passed to your callback function.

Comment: Checking for errors did not help, but I did think about why data would be undefined and I realized that you need to explicitly delineate the file path in order for the .js file to find it. I had assumed that since they were in the same folder, it would already know where it would be located. Thank you!